# LinearGradient Stop px precision

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way to create a LinearGradient with px instead of percents?
Let's say I'd like to have a gradient like this:

White stripe (25px) - Black line (1px) - Gray stripe (25px) - Black line (1px)

I can write this as:

> from 0px 0px to 0px 52px, repeat, white 0%, white 49%, black 49%,
> black 50%, gray 50%, gray 99%, black 99%, black 100%

but this one doesn't guarantee that the 1% is 1px. (1% of 52 is 0.52).
How can I be more precise? Is there any other way?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolorstop) you can specify the color-stop by length (i.e. in pixels). Does `white 0, white 25, black 25, black 26, gray 26, gray 51, black 51, black 52` work?

Comment: @James_D I tried it and indeed works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution provided by James_D**

I was able to declare my gradient like this:

> white 0, white 25, black 25, black 26, gray 26, gray 51, black 51,
> black 52

What a shame there's no information about it:
[LinearGradient official documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html)

Comment: The docs you cite explicitly say "If the proportional variable is set to false, then the start and end points should be specified in the local coordinate system of the shape".

Comment: @James_D Shame on me. I always thought that it's about percentage

Comment: I think "coordinate system" always means some measure based on pixels (not always actual pixels, e.g. if a scale transform is applied to the node). "Proportional" is essentially equivalent to "percentage" (with a factor of 100).

Comment: @James_D _"Proportional" is essentially equivalent to "percentage"_ When you create a gradient from String like me (LinearGradient.valueOf(str)) it is non-proportional by default and my percentage was kind of working, so there's no requirement to use proportional along with percentage. I mean if you want to, you are able to use percents with non-proportional gradient

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that comment. I'm saying "proportional" and "percentage" are basically synonyms. (The only difference is that a proportion ranges from 0 to 1, a percentage ranges from 0 to 100.) If you specify a linear gradient with a string, either you use `%` in the color stop, so by definition it is proportional, or you use pixel values (not proportional). I think the documentation is pretty clear on this.

Comment: @James_D Nevermind, now it's all clear for me, thank you for your help